# Is setting up a server runtime necessary to generate a web service client with CXF in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, cxf, webservice-client

When I go to **file -> new -> other -> web services -> web service client** in Eclipse and select the "Web services runtime" I see "Apache CFX 2.x", but the finish button is disabled and I get the following in the dialog box:

"Choose from the list of runtimes and deployment servers, or use the default settings."

Do I really have to setup a server in order to generate a web service client with CXF in Eclipse?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does seem so.

The CXF client runs in a "Dynamic Web Project" which needs a server runtime. See this [link on the Eclipse forums](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=527116&)