# Easy way to generate web service clients in Java WITHOUT using Axis

Tags: java, web-services

I've always used the web service generation in Eclipse WTP to build my web service clients due to it's relative easy of use.

However, in the last couple years, as I've learned more about it I've seen the error of my ways.

I've read that one should use one of the plethora of other java web service client platforms such as CXF, Metro, etc.

At this point, I don't particularly care which platform I use - so long as it is not Axis.

My question is - the WTP tooling makes it easy to generate web service clients in java. Are there any similar tools, scripts, programs or tutorials that are of similar ease of use?

I don't really have time to learn all the intricacies of SOAP, RPC, etc. so please keep in mind that I'm not really trying to be lazy so much as I am pragmatic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What don't you like about Axis? I'm integrating a .NET solution with Axis web service calls and was wondering what issues you are experiencing.

Comment: Almost everything in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588616/java-webservice-client-best-way) I've experienced. IDK, maybe Axis works better with .Net?

Comment: @Babak Naffas: he probably doesn't like the fact that Axis feels like something designed in the eighties ;)

Comment: I have no love for it currently. Good to know it's not just me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) can generate the soap clients for many multiple java soap stacks like axis 1 & 2, xfire, GStep, JAX-WS, JAX-RPC, JBoss WS, Oracle Proxy, cxf, .Net, GStep. [Here is the tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/tips/generating-client-java-code?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a+javalobby/frontpage+%28Javalobby+/+Java+Zone%29) on how to do it.

Comment: +1 - SOAP UI is a great tool, most useful.  It does a lot more than just generate clients.

Comment: Wow, what a great tool. Thanks!