# org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.Handler

Tags: axis, jboss7.x, classcastexception

I'm migrating an axis 1.2.1 application between two app servers I get the following class cast exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.Handler
```

Has anyone seen this before? 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at [this][1]. Hope this helps!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566580/strange-interaction-with-axis-osgi

Comment: Yeah, checked it. But there is no real resolution from what I can see :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem and for what i see it's seems to be when you use axis in a jar in the root of the deploy dir and a jar in the ear/war module. The classloader instance twice the axis lib, so that generate the problem.

One solution is to move the calling of the axis from the jar in the root of the deploy to a module (like an ear or some like that). I hope this can help you.

Regards