# Applet Web service client, with Eclipse Indigo using Apache CXF,

Tags: applet, cxf, webservice-client, eclipse-indigo

I'm trying to consume a web service within an applet.

For that objective i've tried Apache and Apache2, both with good results
but the problem is that the jar dependencies are far too fat for my application
(the jar for axis or axis2 are over 1.5MB, and the applet is less than 200KB)
So i will try consuming the web service with Apache CXF, hoping that the jars
are at least a bit smaller.

Using eclipse one creates an empty project and in the main classes implements
the applet and blah blah, but to create the web service one must use the web service
wizard.

I've used this wizard before, to consume the web service using Axis, but the moment i choose other options i get this message:

****The Apache CXF 2.x Web service runtime in Tomcat v7.0 Server does not support the client project****

What i´m missing?

I've already installed, CXF 2.x runtime, and the Tomcat 7 Server, and of course the Eclipse Web Tools.

This question [How to generate web service client with Apache CXF in Eclipse Helios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406752/how-to-generate-web-service-client-with-apache-cxf-in-eclipse-helios)
shows a very hard solution and it´s one year old!

is there any other way to consume webservices within an applet?
ksoap2 has no documentation on complex webservices, and ksoap2-android
neither

Sorry for a boring question, but any help is greatly apreciated

Answer (score 3):

Apache CXF 2-x Web service runtime Tomcat Server not support client

The Apache CXF 2.x Web service runtime in Tomcat v7.0 Server does not support the client project

Answer: If you see above error during creating web service client in eclipse using Apache CXF means you are using java project to generate the client from WSDL. Latest version of JAX-WS supports Dynamic Web Module v2.5 and up. So create client using apache CXF first you need to create Dynamic web project.

Once dynamic project created then open web service client wizard to create client from WSDL and issue should be resolved.