# How to call .net webservice from Java

Tags: java, web-services

I have created one Java Software in that I want to call .net webservice.

How to make it possible ?

I see some examples but I don't find any perfect solution.

Comment: Just for clarification. You have got .net webservice and you want to make an HTTP call from Java Code to your .net service?

Comment: Yes, I want to call .net web service.

Comment: It should hardly matter what technology sits behind the web service. Java can consume web services using JAX-WS. See for instance [Metro](https://metro.java.net/).

Answer (score 2):

Web services are universal operating system and language independent. It doesn't matter where the services is or in what language it is written,you just invoke it and it gives you "replay".Probably you must refer to java consuming web services.

Here are two references ;-

1.From MSDN
[Java/.NET Interoperability with the Microsoft.com Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms953968.aspx)

2.[Integrating .NET Web Services with Java and classic ASP Clients for Interoperability](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ankithakur/WSIntegration02132006041221AM/WSIntegration.aspx?ArticleID=a0966837-4a15-4091-b6a7-a751ed3ada85)

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple as long as you don't get into any strange jaxws/WCF interop issues.

1. Get hold of the WSDL from the WCF service. (i.e. http://example.org/service.svc?WSDL usually gets you the WSDL).
2. Generate Web service client from WSDL. You can use wsimport from JDK to do this, there are other options as well, CXF wsdl2java. Plenty of SO threads cover this already: [Java Webservice Client (Best way)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588616/java-webservice-client-best-way/3590252#3590252)
3. Use the java client from plain code to call your .NET service.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways you can do this, depending on what kind of .Net Webservice, you have (WCF / SOAP / RESTful JSON / XML-RPC / etc.), likewise how you interact with it from Java may be as easy as HttpClient + Gson/Castor, or as less simple as setting up WSIT.