# UPDATE - Java Webservice Client (Best way)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-10

I am in the same situation that arises in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588616/java-webservice-client-best-way), but 8 years have passed since it was answered.

I have a WSDL specification and I need to generate a client. I'm working on an SpringBoot project with JDK 10.

So, nowadays what is the best way to go? Is there a new and better way?

Comment: This [Spring Doc](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/) must be more up to date. I do not know if it is the *best* way but worth giving a glance.

Comment: 8 year have passed since it was answered yes, but SOAP web-service have not really evolved :D. So yes jax-ws / spring webservice / CXF are still valid candidate to manage this stuff.